# Why do parentheses affect hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

When I used `respond_with` and passed a literal hash, it gave me the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
`respond_with {:status => "Not found"}`
```

However, when I enclosed the literal hash in parentheses like so:

```
respond_with({:status => "Not found"})
```

the function runs without a hitch. Why do the parentheses make a difference? Isn't a hash an enclosed call?

Comment: I dont exactly know the why. But a good thing to know if that if you want to avoid brackets when using hash as a parameter, you can avoid all of them to make it work: `respond_with :status => "Not found"`

Comment: @TimPetricola Oh wow. That works for multiple values as well. Thanks! Now why can I avoid the brace brackets when using it as a parameter?

Comment: See Holger's answer for that.

Comment: @TimPetricola Yeah. I saw it. Ruby scares me a little bit, sometimes. Its almost too smart. It may cause the start of the android revolution.

Comment: That's why we love it :)

Comment: Those are not brackets. They are parentheses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When calling a method, the opening curly bracket directly after the method name is interpreted as the start of a block. This has precedence over the interpretation as a hash. One way to circumvent the issue is to use parenthesis to enforce the interpretation as a method argument. As an example, please note the difference in meaning of these two method calls:

```
# interpreted as a block
[:a, :b, :c].each { |x| puts x }

# interpreted as a hash
{:a => :b}.merge({:c => :d})
```

Another way is to just get rid of the curly brackets as you can always skip the brackets on the last argument of a method. Ruby is "clever" enough to interpret everything which looks like an association list at the end of an argument list as a single hash. Please have a look at this example:

```
def foo(a, b)
  puts a.inspect
  puts b.inspect
end

foo "hello", :this => "is", :a => "hash"
# prints this:
# "hello"
# {:this=>"is", :a=>"hash"}
```

Comment: Ruby does have a lot of cool "assumptions". What do you mean by "at the end"? Could you have parameters before it and then still have the bracketless hash?

Comment: @RileyE The first parameter to `respond_with` are the resources you're serving back, and it's an arbitrary number of resources.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah. The docs you referenced were a big help. Sorry for not understanding them when I asked.

Comment: Wow. You guys are amazing. This makes so much more sense than any googling could have. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RileyE The [respond_with docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) detail the method's arguments. The first parameter is an arbitrary number of resources.

Comment: @RileyE You were misusing "brackets" in the question for "parentheses", and now in the comment, you are using it (as in "bracketless") to mean "(curly) braces". Your use of the words is terrible. Parenthesis, (curly) brace, and bracket are all different things. At least, you should be consistent on which word means what.

Comment: @sawa I'm sorry to have offended you with my use of the words, however, by definition, they are still all brackets. There are many ways to refer to each different type and there isn't really a set way. However, from now on, I will aim to be more clear with my explanations about the different types of brackets.

Comment: @RileyE You didn't offend me at all. It was just confusing. That is all. Sorry if my words were too strong.